# pressing enter in the magit "git log", can the commit be shown in the full height of the screen instead of a half screen?

Tags: magit

When I press RET in the magit "git log", can the commit be shown in the full height of the screen instead of a half screen?

```
RET runs the command magit-show-commit (found in
magit-commit-section-map), which is an autoloaded interactive compiled
Lisp function in ‘magit-diff.el’.

It is bound to RET and C-<return>.

(magit-show-commit REV &optional ARGS FILES MODULE)
```

Comment: `(setq magit-display-buffer-function 'magit-display-buffer-fullcolumn-most-v1)` seems to work on my side, but I don't really the doc of this function carefully.

Comment: I tried it once no luck will try again